# does mongodb insert creates new schema

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, monk, database

i got an existing mongoDB server that is already running and storing data,lets say it contains the collections: "**name**" and "**id**".
i store these collections by using `insert` command.
now i need  to add a new collection, lets say "**address**".
can i simply add "**address**" collection also by using `insert`?
does mongoDB creates a new schema every time i use `insert` or it just updates the schema? i mean, will mongoDB create a **new** **schema** containing the three from above or it'll just update the existing one with a new one?
ill explain myself better with the existing code:

```
var env = {
    'User': 'aaa',
    'Pass': '123',
    'stats_a': 'collectionA',
    'db_name': 'localhost:27017/nodedb',
    'proxy_name': 'proxy',
    'proxy_port': 8080
};
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk(env.db_name);
//now i will get the collection and store data in it
 var CollectionA = db.get(env.stats_a);
// create data to insert...
      CollectionA.insert(data)
```

now i want to add a new parameter to `var env` and then insert in like this:

```
var env = {
    'User': 'aaa',
    'Pass': '123',
    'stats_a': 'collectionA',
//new collection
        'stats_b': 'collectionB',
//new collection
        'db_name': 'localhost:27017/nodedb',
        'proxy_name': 'proxy',
        'proxy_port': 8080
    };
    var monk = require('monk');
    var db = monk(env.db_name);
    //now i will get the collection and store data in it
     var CollectionA = db.get(env.stats_a);
     var CollectionB = db.get(env.stats_b);
    // create data to insert...
          CollectionA.insert(data)
          CollectionB.insert(data)
```

is the code after the update will work if i use (assuming time_stamp exist):

```
 var retJson = {A: {}, B: {}};
     var CollectionA = db.get(env.stats_a);
        var CollectionB = db.get(env.stats_b);

    CollectionA.findOne({}, {sort: {time_stamp: -1}}, function (err, doc) {
        retJson.A = doc;
        CollectionB.findOne({}, {sort: {time_stamp: -1}}, function (err, doc) {
            retJson.B = doc;
            res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.send(retJson);
        });
    });
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your terminology is not quite correct in your question. But I think this is a good summary of your request: You have a mongodb collection that contains documents with **name** and **id** fields. You created these documents using the `insert` command.

---

**Your Question 1: "can i simply add "address" collection also by using insert?"**

I think you are asking if you can add a new field (i.e., address) to a document using `insert`.

**No**. The [insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) command is used *only* for inserting new documents. If you use it to update then the command will fail because your **_id** key is a duplicate **or** it will create a new document if the _id isn't given or doesn't exist already.

---

**Your Question 2: "does mongoDB creates a new schema every time i use insert or it just updates the schema?"**

Your wording is confusing. I think you mean "document" instead of "schema".

Anyway, if you use the `insert` command to insert a document in a collection *and the collection does not exist* then the collection will be created *and* the document will be inserted into that new collection.

If the collection already exists then a new document will be created inside of the collection.

---

**Your Question 3: "will mongoDB create a new schema containing the three from above or it'll just update the existing one with a new one?"**

Again, I think you mean "document" instead of "schema".

When using `insert` mongodb will create a new document as mentioned in the other two questions.

---

**Summary**

In order to do the updates you should use the [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) command. Realize that the `update` command has an `upsert` parameter that if **true** creates a new document when no document matches the query criteria. This might be helpful to you.

To help with your terminology:

- [collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-collection) - analogous to a "table" in RDBMS; exists within a database; may contain many documents
- [document](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-document) - a record in a mongodb collection
- [field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-field) - a name-value pair in a document

Comment: ok thank! i messed up the terminology,sorry.
what i meant to say was: if i add a new parameter in `var evn` called `stats_b` and then use :